# managed metadata field isn't getting associated to a site column from a custom list create from VS solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, managed-metadata, visual-studio-2015

Here I have created the custom managed metadata column in visual studio.as like below.

```
 <Field
           Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti"
           DisplayName="Document Type"
           StaticName="DocumentType"
           Name="DocumentType"
           Group="ManagedMetaData"
           ShowField="Term1033"
           Description="Managed Metadata for the Document Type."
           Required="FALSE"
           EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
           ID="{8B2F26F1-9A2B-41E5-BFC3-63D9CB4A7703}"
           DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
           Overwrite="TRUE"
           Mult="FALSE">
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           p4:type="q6:string"
                           xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{28226668-3DDE-46F2-875B-CA7A873A468E}</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
```

which I am including in the Content Type and binding this content type to custom list(Here i am creating a calendar list).

and there is some c# code which I am Adding to the event receiver. that is as below.

```
 string groupName = "groupName";
        Dictionary<string, string> termDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Document Type", "{8B2F26F1-9A2B-41E5-BFC3-63D9CB4A7703}" } };
        public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb currentSite = null;
            if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPWeb)
            {
                currentSite = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
            }
            else if (properties.Feature.Parent is SPSite)
            {
                currentSite = ((SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent).RootWeb;
            }
            if (currentSite != null)
            {
                CreateGroupTermSet(currentSite);
                foreach (var termItem in termDictionary)
                {
                    AssociateMetadata(currentSite, new Guid(termItem.Value), termItem.Key);
                }
            }
            currentSite.Close();
        }

        private void CreateGroupTermSet(SPWeb currentSite)
        {
            TaxonomySession ts = new TaxonomySession(currentSite.Site);
            TermStore termStore = ts.TermStores[0];
            if (!termStore.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == groupName))
            {
                Group group = termStore.CreateGroup(groupName);
                foreach (var termName in termDictionary)
                {
                    if (!group.TermSets.Any(g => g.Name == termName.Key))
                    {
                        TermSet termSetDepartment = group.CreateTermSet(termName.Key);
                        termSetDepartment.IsOpenForTermCreation = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            termStore.CommitAll();
        }

        private void AssociateMetadata(SPWeb currentSite, Guid fieldId, string termSetName)
        {
            if (currentSite.Site.RootWeb.Fields.Contains(fieldId))
            {
                TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(currentSite.Site);

                TermStoreCollection termStores = session.TermStores;
                if (session.TermStores.Count != 0)
                {
                    var termStore = session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"];

                    var termGroup = termStore.Groups[groupName];
                    var termSet = termGroup.TermSets[termSetName];

                    TaxonomyField field = currentSite.Site.RootWeb.Fields[fieldId] as TaxonomyField;

                    field.SspId = termSet.TermStore.Id;
                    field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
                    field.TargetTemplate = string.Empty;
                    field.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
                    field.CreateValuesInEditForm = true;
                    field.Open = true;
                    field.Update();
                }
            }
        }
```

after doing all this stuff i am simply deploying this solution on site collection where i am trying to add the term inside the list but that filed is disabled which is not allowing me to enter term.that looks a like as below snap.
[image]

but here if i am creating a any other list manualy in site collection and assigning the same content type to it then there i can add this data.you can see that in below snap.
[image]
so here i am not able to fugure it out like what is the wrong thing i am doing?

Comment: did you checked the column property in list? Is it coming from content type or not?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the Issue by Adding the note filed to that metadata column as like below and Adding the same Note field column to the List.

```
<Field
           Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti"
           DisplayName="Document Type"
           StaticName="DocumentType"
           Name="DocumentType"
           Group="ManagedMetaData"
           ShowField="Term1033"
           Description="Managed Metadata for the Document Type."
           Required="FALSE"
           EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
           ID="{8B2F26F1-9A2B-41E5-BFC3-63D9CB4A7703}"
           DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
           Overwrite="TRUE"
           Mult="FALSE">
    <Customization>
      <ArrayOfProperty>
        <Property>
          <Name>TextField</Name>
          <Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           p4:type="q6:string"
                           xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{28226668-3DDE-46F2-875B-CA7A873A468E}</Value>
        </Property>
      </ArrayOfProperty>
    </Customization>
  </Field>
 <Field Type="Note"
           DisplayName="DocumentType_0"
           StaticName="DocumentTypeTaxHTField0"
           Name="DocumentTypeTaxHTField0"
           ID="{28226668-3DDE-46F2-875B-CA7A873A468E}"
           ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
           Required="FALSE"
           Hidden="TRUE"
           CanToggleHidden="TRUE"
           Group="ManagedMetaData"
           RowOrdinal="0"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check te sequence how the list is created. First deploy site columns and contenttypes to your site using a different feature with an event receiver to set the tax field. In different feature add the list to your site.